# Getting error (File does not exist) during submitting spark job via spark-submit in yarn cluster

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I have set up a yarn cluster with following configuration in **core-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
    <property>
            <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
            <value>hdfs://localhost:54310</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

I am submitting spark job with following command;

```
./spark-submit --class main.MainClass --deploy-mode cluster --master yarn sparkJob.jar [options]
```

Now I am getting an exception after failing the job,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://localhost:54310/user/root/.sparkStaging/application_1489672189113_0002/__spark_conf__.zip
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$18.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1122)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$18.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1114)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1114)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anonfun$6.apply(ApplicationMaster.scala:158)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anonfun$6.apply(ApplicationMaster.scala:155)
at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.<init>(ApplicationMaster.scala:155)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anonfun$main$1.apply$mcV$sp(ApplicationMaster.scala:748)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$1.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:71)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$1.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:70)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1656)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil.runAsSparkUser(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:70)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:747)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.main(ApplicationMaster.scala)
```

I am very new with **yarn**. Can you give any hint about this exception. If any more resource required please mention.

I am starting the SparkSession in my java code as follow

```
ss=SparkSession.builder()
                  .appName("appname")
                  .getOrCreate();
```

Anyone please, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you messing with the default filesystem?

Comment: I tried in various way. Can you just suggest what to do. I am simply lost. I think you understand what I am trying to achieve.